# Multiple Login forms on the one page

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am using the Login plugin and have 2 login forms that log the user into a different user group depending on which one they submit.

However, it does not seem they want to cooperate, being on the same page.

My code is as such:

```
<div id="seekersloginslider" class="ctaslider">
    <h2>Job Seekers Login</h2>
    [[!Login? &loginResourceId=`32`]]
</div>

<div id="employersloginslider" class="ctaslider">
    <h2>Employers Login</h2>
    [[!Login? &loginResourceId=`18`]]
</div>
```

No matter which form I use I will always be directed to Resource 32. If I try logging in with the lower 'Employers' form it will redirect to resource 32 and cause a 404.

If I remove the upper, 'Job Seekers' form, the lower login form works as expected, redirecting me to Resource 18.

Does anyone know a way to have both forms working on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all because first snippet catch the call. Your second snippet can't react.

You have to manipulate with `submitVar` or `actionKey` parameter. Just [rtfm](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/login/login.login#Login.Login-Properties). You can get some information [there](http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2011/03/08/modx-revolution-for-complete-beginners-part-9-using-formit-for-contact-forms/) also.